# How to start auto Kibana after system boot (Linux)

Tags: linux, git-bash, linux-server, elasticsearch

So we are hosting our development environment on our internal LAN network. However, we keep facing an issue of restarting kibana every few minutes. Also if there is a way that I can schedule it to auto start on boot. we start it using git bash and connect to the server port to access kibana. Is there a way to auto start kibana as a service on boot or any .bat script that can be scheduled on boot to keep kibana up and running without the need to restart it again.

Comment: Welcome aboard. I would advise you to delete this question and ask it again [our Linux sister site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is that Linux? You mention git-bash and .BAT files which are both only on Windows?